# SUBSTRING in COUNT query not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I apologise if the title is ambiguous.

I have a table called `data` and in that table is a column called `barcode`
The barcodes look similar to this:

```
TEST210001m1c8Wsa
```

The format of the barcode is as follows:

Job: TEST2

Auto-increment nr: 10001

Type identifier: m1

Unique ID: c8Wsa

I am trying to count the amount of barcodes in the column of the whole table that match the Job, type ID and unique ID. I am not concerned about the auto increment. I'm using the below query but it doesn't seems to work as I expect:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE barcode LIKE 'test2%' AND SUBSTRING('m1', LENGTH(barcode)-7,2)='m1' AND RIGHT('c8Wsa', 5)='c8Wsa'
```

I'm positive that I am using the `SUBSTRING` incorrectly because if I remove it the query returns results as expected. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm certain it's something small that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify column name for first parameter in `substring()` function and same for `right()` function also

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data 
WHERE barcode LIKE 'test2%' AND SUBSTRING(barcode, LENGTH(barcode)-6,2)='m1' 
AND RIGHT(barcode , 5)='c8Wsa'
```

Comment: Since I'm using the query in my C++ code, this answer works perfectly for what I want to do! I knew it was something small that I did wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a sum instead like this.

```
Select sum(charindex, barcode, 'm1') from table where 
barcode like 'Test2%' and barcode like '%c8Wsa''
```

That way you will effectively count all of the substrings for the barcodes filtered by your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this using `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM data
WHERE barcode REGEXP 'TEST2[0-9]{5}m1c8Wsa';
```

This assumes that the auto increment number would always be fixed at 5 digits.  If it could be variable, then you may use the following pattern:

```
TEST2[0-9]+m1c8Wsa
```